# Sharing variables between the same file

Tags: javascript, html

All my 5 html files that all go to each other using links and share the same javascript script  `<script src="indexJS.js"></script>` In the javascript file I have the following

```
let shoppingCart = []

function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    shoppingCart.push(clicked_id);
    console.log(shoppingCart);
}
```

Basically when I click a button, I get the id of the button and then add it to an array.  What I want to happen is when I go to another file, it says that shoppingCart array between files.  Right now every time I go to a new HTML file, the shoppingCart array resets.

I DON'T want to use any other languages except javascript.  No node or anything please, I'm not sure if its possible though.

Comment: You need a storage, therefore use ```localStorage```, so everytime the browser reload. the array will not reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` to persist data across different pages without relying on backend technologies. You can modify your JavaScript code to store and retrieve the shoppingCart array in localStorage via like this :

```
let shoppingCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shoppingCart')) || [];

function reply_click(clicked_id) {
    shoppingCart.push(clicked_id);
    console.log(shoppingCart);

    
    localStorage.setItem('shoppingCart', JSON.stringify(shoppingCart)); // Update shoppingCart array to localStorage
}
```

Similarly, you can fetch items from local storage like this :

```
localStorage.getItem('shoppingCart', JSON.stringify(shoppingCart)); // Get shoppingCart array from localStorage
```

Comment: Little simpler if anyone else has this question but it seems ```let shoppingCart = [localStorage.getItem("ShoppingCart")]``` also works